# Trying to understand a simple C copy function

Tags: c, function, while-loop, void

I'm trying to understand function which copies characters from stdin but I can't understand the while loop and the code following it exactly.....
 How does the while loop here work??
From what I understand it means until `ith` character from `to[]` isn't equal to `ith` character of `from[]` keep on adding `i` am I correct??
If yes than how does the ith character be equal in both the variables ??

Here is a short code :

```
void copy(char to[] , char from[])   
{
    int i;
    i = 0 ;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: It's a string copy. It's assigning the i'th value of from into to. It then checks to see if this value is a "NUL", if it isn't (i.e. we're not at the end of the string) then increment i and keep copying.

Comment: "it means until ith character from to[] **isn't equal to** " - `=` is very different to `==`!

Comment: nit-pick: I'd probably change this function to `void copy(char *to, const char *from)`, and preferably -though that would require you to refactor your existing code- `int copy (char *to, const char *from, size_t max)`. The latter function avoiding overflow, and returning the number of chars that were copied

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem wouldn't it become unnecessary if I define MAXLENGTH = x at the begining??

Comment: @ArchKudo: maybe, but that'd make your copy function rather specific (as in: not re-usable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewriting it might help:

```
do{
  to[i] = from[i];
  ++i;
}while (from[i-1] != '\0') // -1 here because we incremented i in the line before and need to check the copied position
```

Do you understand now?

Comment: So it is making it copy characters from to[] to from[], am I right??

Comment: You read assignments from right to left. So it copies, as the name implies from `from` to `to`.

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the `while` loop uses the fact that in C an assignment expression has a value which is the value assigned in the assignment. This means that the condition in the `while` loop can be implemented to have a side-effect, namely the element-wise assignment of the source to the destination. In total, the actual work of the loop is carried out in its condition, while the loop's body just increases the index `i`.

Answer (score 1):

It's how assignments work.  An assignment (a = b) returns a value (b).  What you're doing there, is moving from[i] to to[i], and comparing the return value (in this case, from[i]) to the character '\0'.

The null character (0x00) terminates any string, and is thus the terminating character of the string you're copying.

I'd be careful with this code, however, as you don't check the bounds on the array and are leaving yourself open to a segmentation fault if you were to encounter a string that isn't properly null terminated, or where the to[] string is too short.

Answer (score 0):

It first copy `from` `ith` character to `to` `ith` position and check that, if its the end of string. if not then it increments i(position or index that will point now to next character) and perform this operation until its matches end of string i.e `'\0'` .

Answer (score 0):

Your code is the same as

```
void copy(char to[] , char from[])   
{
    int i;
    i = 0 ;
    while (from[i] != '\0')
      {
        to[i] = from[i];
        ++i;
      }
    to[i] = '\0';
}
```

So while it's not at the end of to, it continue copying from in to.

Comment: This will abort if `\0` is the first character in `from` without copying it to `to`.